# VBA Array equalled to Range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Just a quick question regarding VBA. I have this block of code

```
Dim colEmployees As New Collection
Dim recEmployee As New clsEmployee
Dim LastRow As Integer, myCount As Integer
Dim EmpArray As Variant

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
EmpArray = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 4))
```

and this on the spreadsheet...[image]

now i have done a lot of reading to grasp how array are working and i have seen exaples like

```
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim myArray (1 to 10, 1 to 20)
myArray = Array(“Name”, “Address”, “Phone”, “Email”)
```

and i totally understand them but when you have an array equaled like this

```
EmpArray = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 4))
```

How can you actually save the data in a one dimensional Array such as EmpArray? Don't you need one dimension for Rows and one for Columns? I mean how the array will actually store the data-by what order ("Tracy", "Bill", "1651", "1509",....) or ("Tracy", "1651", "25", "45")? Generally storing Ranges in Arrays especially one-dimension ones looks really odd to me. And 3 of my VBA books don't delve to this a little deeper...

If it is a 2-dimensional Array how is it posible that the code continues like:

```
Sub EmpPayCollection()
Dim colEmployees As New Collection
Dim recEmployee As New clsEmployee
Dim LastRow As Integer, myCount As Integer
Dim EmpArray As Variant

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
EmpArray = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 4))

For myCount = 1 To **UBound(EmpArray)**
Set recEmployee = New clsEmployee
With recEmployee
.EmpName = EmpArray(myCount, 1)
.EmpID = EmpArray(myCount, 2)
.EmpRate = EmpArray(myCount, 3)
.EmpWeeklyHrs = EmpArray(myCount, 4)
colEmployees.Add recEmployee, .EmpID
End With
Next myCount
MsgBox “Number of Employees: “ & colEmployees.Count & Chr(10) & _
“Employee(2) Name: “ & colEmployees(2).EmpName
MsgBox “Tracy’s Weekly Pay: $” & colEmployees(“1651”).EmpWeeklyPay
Set recEmployee = Nothing
End Sub
```

How come it use UBound without clearly stating the dimension picked? I know it is optional... but could you factor also this in to your answer...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't store the data as a single dimensioned array, it stores it as a 2-dimensional 1 based array. The value property of a range (which contains multiple cells) returns a 2-dimensional array (value is implicit here since it is the default property of a range). In your example, the array therefore looks like:

```
Tracy   1651    25  45
Bill    1509    25  50
```

With the first dimension specifying the row and the second the column - like the cell object.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sir what do you mean by saying ...a 2-dimensional 1 based...?

Comment: I mean that it is a 2 dimensional array with the lower bounds of the array starting at 1 as opposed to 0

Comment: Sir, Sorry for dealying that long i almost got it i just made a small adjustment and re-edited a little bit the post so that i can have my question solved in entirety.

Comment: `Ubound()` defaults to the first dimension if the optional dimension parameter is omitted. It is functionally the same as `For myCount = 1 To UBound(EmpArray,1)` So the code is looping through the first dimension - i.e the Rows